# How to optimize the data fetching technique in my application in c# winforms.!

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, gridview, datagridview, query-optimization

I have a gridview in c# winforms which shows almost 45264 records which are binded then fetched from database. If i want to update/delete any record then every time the whole data is fetched again from database and that database is connected on 70 Systems. If any user updates or deletes any record then whole database just gets all hanged up and slow and also the application gets slow as well. So what should be the solution for this ?
How to optimize this behavior ?

Comment: You don't need to load all records to your `DataGridView`. For example you can load paged data and show 50 record per page.

Comment: It's not related to significance of data. I suppose the data is very important and you want to load all data to grid. How many records can you see in first look? What should you do to view remaining records? You should scroll or go to next page. You also can use `VirtualMode` of `DataGridView` to implement custom loading of data when scrolling and then you can avoid loading all data. But the core of all solutions is the same, *You don't need to load all records*

Comment: i know but my manager not allowed for paging in  @DataGridView .. ok thanks dear